# How is submillisecond latency I/O possible, given large time slices between context switches?

Tags: multithreading, performance, io, low-latency

In Linux, each thread is given time a time slice of 10ms to execute before the context switches. How is sub-millisecond latency for network I/O possible then - for example, where a UDP packet is sent for a DNS type query and a response is received in less than 0.2 ms (I have measured this to occur)?

A sender sends the packet using datagram socket.send() and a receiver is running on another thread, and calls socket.receive(). Even assuming a non blocking (in OS layers, etc.) send, when the response does come back it (it=the OS, via an interrupt, etc.) will have to unblock that waiting thread on socket.receive(), and that thread will not get its time slice until the currently executing thread runs out its time slice, which is on the order of 10ms...50x greater than 0.2. (Also, the context switch itself takes some significant time, which might be on the order of .1 or so millis.) So how are such low latencies achieved?

(I realize one solution might be that multiple cores/processors are available to instantly run the thread as soon as the response packet is received, but is this the only way? I.e. is submillisecond latency possible on a single core?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about about system/network capabilties and architecture, not programming.

Comment: When you send a DNS query, you typically *wait for a response*.  And a blocking wait would end the thread's time slice.

Comment: That 10ms is when the context switch happens if there is no other reason to do it sooner.

Comment: @AndrewBarber : This question is in large part about programming, because it asks about the mechanism of how a submillisecond latency IO can be/is implemented in both user code and OS layers.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey : Are you saying that as soon as the response UDP packet is received, the waiting receiver thread is unblocked by the OS (preempting the currently running thread)? If so, then why should that currently running thread be preempted - maybe what it's doing is more important than (user mode) processing of the incoming packet?

Comment: That's not really the kind of question for here, though. We're more about specific bits of code being written. There are other sites for broader topics like this. I think it's an interesting question, but just isn't the best fit here. That said, I think you've basically got the answer above.

Comment: @Tim The question is whether submillisecond I/O is possible. Whether it's desirable is a different question. If what the other thread is doing is more important, submillisecond I/O is still possible by pre-empting it, but may not be desirable.

Comment: You are msotly correct, and the good I/O performance is the most important advantage of preemptive multitaskers, but'and that thread will not get its time slice until the currently executing thread runs out its time slice' is, in general, wrong.  On most systems, threads made ready on I/O completion are run 'immediately', possibly preempting an already running thread.  Preemptive kernels try to match up threads with immediately-available resources, so try to forget about that 'time-slice' 'quantum' shit - it will only confuse you.

Comment: Also, typical context-switches take much less than 100us.  On my system, making another thread running on an inter-thread signal takes 6-8us if the system is not overloaded. Making a thread ready on an driver interrupt will take longer because the driver code itself has to run before the reschedule/dispatch.